# H2 database can't find table in mv.db file-- but overwrites existing one

Tags: java, h2

Using javax.sql.DataSource to manage an H2 database saved to a file named mydb.mv.db file with a connection string as follows:

```
jdbc:h2:mydb;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;MODE=MySQL;
```

In addition, we have tested with the following connection string:

```
jdbc:h2:mydb;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;MODE=MySQL;INIT=create table if not exists mytable(...);
```

The mv.db file already contains a table with about 600k of data in it. The data includes normal stuff (ints and varchars) as well as a longblob field. My distribution includes its own JRE7 bundle.

We've deployed to several customers running Windows7. Everything works as expected for everyone-- except one. For that customer, the table isn't found and a "no such table" error is thrown. If we include the "create table if not exists" in the connection string INIT, then the table gets recreated and the file size shrinks to 12k (which seems fishy-- like the file was entirely ignored and simply overwritten with a blank database).

What could possibly be causing this to work on some systems and fail on others (all Win 7 / 64-bit)?

For further background, here are some of the possible reasons we considered and ruled out:

- file path confusion? when we use the connection string that contains the INIT statement, the table gets recreated, and the file size significantly shrinks. So it seems to be finding the right file. Furthermore, when we subsequently save data to this table, after it has been recreated, it persists
- file permissions insufficient? in the problem environment, we manually set the permissions to Full Control for Everyone and the problem persisted. Conversely, in our test environment we set mydb.mv.db to read-only and the problem does not occur.
- case-sensitivity? tried DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false in config
- different schema? does not explain how the file size is shrinking so much (which suggests that the pre-existing table is being replaced)

Comment: Can you connect to the database via H2 console or SQLWorkbench or similar tool and run the same query that gives you the "no such table" error?

Comment: Because the problem environment is located on a clean customer installation under their control, for now I can only observe the problem in their environment via secure screen share, and ask them to perform a few basic diagnostics using stock Windows tools while I watch-- but I cannot recreate it on our own systems under our direct control.

Comment: Can you get a copy/backup of the database in question to attempt it on your system - It might be that the database needs repairing.

Comment: Actually, we created the mv.db database file in question that contains the table that is not being found. Unfortunately, I cannot obtain a copy of the overwritten mv.db file after the unfound table is replaced with an empty one (at least not for now, though I may eventually be able to after a series of approvals). Oddly, the exact same mv.db file works find on our system and other clients' systems.